# Playgrounds broken in Xcode 8.3

Tags: ios, xcode

Since I started working Xcode 8.2 (and 8.3 lately), playgrounds are completely broken for me.

When opening a playground I see the message "Failed to launch process. Error returned in reply: Connection Interrupted"

Complete re-installation of Xcode or removing / re-creating /private/tmp folder (as suggested by some other posts) did not help.

Did someone encounter a similar problem? Are there other known work-arounds?
(http://www.openradar.me/31296836)

Here is some sample output from CoreSimulator.log

```
Mar 28 16:19:30 sergey-macbook com.apple.dt.Xcode[6955] <Error>: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error returned in reply: Connection interrupted}
Mar 28 16:19:30 sergey-macbook com.apple.dt.Xcode[6955] <Error>: Error looking up host support port: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error returned in reply: Connection interrupted}
Mar 28 16:19:30 sergey-macbook com.apple.dt.Xcode[6955] <Error>: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error returned in reply: Connection interrupted}
Mar 28 16:19:30 sergey-macbook com.apple.dt.Xcode[6955] <Error>: Error looking up host support port: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error returned in reply: Connection interrupted}
Mar 28 16:19:30 sergey-macbook com.apple.dt.Xcode[6955] <Error>: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error returned in reply: Connection interrupted}
Mar 28 16:19:30 sergey-macbook com.apple.dt.Xcode[6955] <Error>: Error looking up host support port: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error returned in reply: Connection interrupted}
Mar 28 16:19:40 sergey-macbook CoreSimulatorService[5859] <Error>: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=163 "Unable to lookup in current state: Shutting Down" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup in current state: Shutting Down}
Mar 28 16:19:40 sergey-macbook CoreSimulatorService[5859] <Error>: Error from finding pasteboard support port, Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=163 "Unable to lookup in current state: Shutting Down" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup in current state: Shutting Down}
Mar 28 16:19:40 sergey-macbook CoreSimulatorService[5859] <Error>: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=163 "Unable to lookup in current state: Shutting Down" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup in current state: Shutting Down}
Mar 28 16:19:40 sergey-macbook CoreSimulatorService[5859] <Error>: Error Domain=com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimError Code=163 "Unable to lookup in current state: Shutting Down" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Unable to lookup in current state: Shutting Down}
Mar 28 16:19:40 sergey-macbook com.apple.dt.Xcode[6955] <Error>: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error returned in reply: Connection interrupted}
Mar 28 16:19:40 sergey-macbook com.apple.dt.Xcode[6955] <Error>: Error from finding pasteboard support port, Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Software caused connection abort" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error returned in reply: Connection interrupted}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Note by the creator of Timing: this issue no longer occurs as of Timing 1.8.1 and Timing 2.0.**

iOS playgrounds work ok in Xcode 8.3.x on my MacBook, but I got the launching simulator errors on my MBP. The MacBook is for travelling, so has a minimal set of apps. In particular, it has fewer app icons in the status menu bar.

So on my MBP, I quit all of those that aren't on the MB, and hey presto, playgrounds ran! I started the apps one by one, and it was [Timing](https://timingapp.com/?lang=en) that brought back the launching simulator error — closing the menu bar icon fixed it again, even though Timing app itself was still running.

Not picking on Timing especially; could be any quick-access app in your menu bar.

Before this, I had reinstalled Sierra, but not a clean install. That would've been the next step.

Comment: Hi Audrey, Daniel, the developer of Timing here. Thank you for pointing this out! I now know about the issue and will investigate it next week. Until then, could you please check if running the following command in Terminal alleviates the issue: `sqlite3 ~/Library/Application\ Support/info.eurocomp.Timing*/ActivityStore.db "update zapplication set zapplescripttrackingdisabled = 1 where zbundleidentifier like '%xcode%'"` . Unfortunately, this will reduce Timing's accuracy of tracking Xcode, but it should be better than nothing :-) Please do let me know if this command works for you!

Comment: Thanks to Audrey - disabling Timing has worked for me. I ran the Terminal command as suggested by @MrMage. It took a restart of the Timing app and Xcode (maybe one of these would have worked), but iOS playgrounds are now working with Timing running. Hopefully an update will fix this issue, and then I will need the Terminal command to reverse this work-around.

Comment: Oh.  My.  God.  I have lost at least 8 hours trying to fix this problem.  It never occurred to me that Timing2 could be the problem.  Confirming that existing the Timing2 app, running the Sql command, and restarting Xcode fixed the problem.

Comment: Great answer!!! I have been troubled with this issue for more than half a year and even don't know why. I found this answer by chance and it works like a charm. This might be the most valuable answer for me which I found in stackoverflow!

Comment: You can't imagine how much time I spent on this. I updated OS, Xcode and restarted my MB many times. Finally its because of Timing app. Uninstalled!

Comment: @HossamGhareeb FYI, Timing 1.8.1 and Timing 2.1.1 do not have this issue anymore.

Answer (score 2):

workaround provided by an engineer at apple
run below command in terminal after quitting Xcode
`defaults write com.apple.dt.xcode IDEPlaygroundDisableSimulatorAlternateFramebuffer -bool YES`

Comment: A Google search on IDEPlaygroundDisableSimulatorAlternateFramebuffer shows that this workaround was provided for an entirely different problem. Are you sure that it's addressing the crashing Simulator service as well?

Comment: After running this my playground crashed , Now I have installed the previous version of `Xcode that is 8.2.1`  , I think the problem is related `isUserInteractionEnabled` , every time I try to interact it crashes

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried deleting your derived data via XCode?

`Shift+Alt+Command+K`

OR the fastest way is open terminal and past the following:

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData
```

Also ensure that there are no simulators or other versions of a playground running in the background.

Comment: Complete reinstallation of Xcode includes wiping derived data and everything Xcode related. I just ended up clean installing macOS (as the last resort), which eliminated the problem for me, but did not shed any light on what was wrong. Full reinstall of the OS is a rather costly solution for this sort of problems :-(

Answer (score 0):

(Unfortunately) I solved the problem by clean installing macOS (which is not the proper way of solving it, of course, but I needed to get playgrounds to work ASAP).

Answer (score 0):

**tl;dr** My problems went away after checking if all simulators were installed (in Xcode Settings > Components), closing all projects which were heavily using `IBDesignable` and restarting the playground.

---

I don't know if this helps in any way but might as well post it;

The first thing I checked was if I had all iOS simulators installed in Xcode. Surprisingly updating to Xcode 8.3 also removed my iOS 10.0 simulator; reinstalled the simulator and reopened Xcode.

Afterwards did a search on google and found a similar [question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/206547/connection-interrupted-error-in-ios-simulators-after-updating-to-xcode-7).

After reading the question I remembered I had an other project open in which I was heavily using `IBDesignable` for testing purposes. Closing this project and restarting the playground solved my problems.

This might have had nothing to do with the playgrounds, but it *did* fixed my problems.