# Xcode error connecting to simulator "Software caused connection abort"

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

When I try to run my project through the Xcode simulator, it keeps giving me the error "Software caused connection abort".

Tried restarting the simulator & Xcode, and I recently deleted the DerivedData folder [as suggested in this post about broken playgrounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43072476/832136) so that also didn't help.

Comment: To me it happened, when sometime back I opened two different Xcode app parallel. 
Just quitting the simulator and the Xcode and then reopening Xcode solved the issue for me.

Comment: Quit all versions of Xcode and Simulator completely. Re-open and run.

Answer (score 108, accepted):

**QUICK FIX**

This is happening because you have multiple versions of Xcode installed. MacOS unfortunately only supports running one version of Xcode at a time, and it needs to know the location of the currently running version. To sort things out, choose one of the following:

**Quit all instances of Xcode and restart it**

Try one of the other options below if that hasn't solved it.

**Using the command line:**

1. run   `sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/your_custom_folder_if_needed/Xcode.app`
2. Restart your terminal and Xcode and it will work just fine.

**No-command line users:**

1. Quit all instances of Xcode
2. Start the instance of Xcode that you want to use
3. Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations
4. Select the correct version in Command Line Tools
5. Done!

Comment: It's easy to get into this state if using different XCode version (beta, released). Can confirm, both of these work.

Comment: Remember to close other tools too, like the Simulator for instance.

Answer (score 56):

It's due to **multiple Xcode** installed in your system. This is how you make it work:

1. Quit all running Xcodes
2. Re-launch Xcode
3. Go to Xcode > Preferences > Locations
4. Change to the correct version in `Command Line Tools`

Clean project and clear Derived data if necessary, then run!

Comment: Just restarting the computer, running the app on an iPhone and then trying the Simulator again resolved it for me: https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/235094#235094

Comment: This solution fixed my issue and I too had 8.2.1 and 8.3.2 running in my mac

Comment: Hi, I have this same issue but there are no multiple versions in my Command Line Tools in Xcode > Preference > Locations, what else can I do?

Comment: Can you quit and re-launch Xcode. Will it happen again?

Answer (score 11):

In my case quitting and re-launching given Xcode was enough. I had two Xcodes, stable and beta.

Answer (score 0):

For me, restarting the Mac OS worked (multiple times).