# Receive failed with error “Software caused connection abort”

Tags: ios, swift, deep-linking, appdelegate, urlsession

I got this error with application connection lost. While redirecting from another app to my app I face this issue.This issue triggered only on live app, getting error with connection lost and while debugging with Xcode getting error but redirected to specific view controller successfully I used deep linking with url scheme for handling response from another app. Still not getting clarity to what exact issue is there because not able to debug live app issue. Working on iOS 13.2 In AppDelegate:

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

let components = NSURLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)
let params = components?.queryItems
signedResponse = (params?.first(where:{$0.name == "signedResponse"})?.value)!

self.decodedMsgString = String(data:Data(base64Encoded: signedResponse)!,encoding:.utf8)!

print("decodedMsgString : \(decodedMsgString)")


//Call API here

return true

}
```

Comment: May be this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43527115/xcode-error-connecting-to-simulator-software-caused-connection-abort